# Why are parenthesis needed

Tags: php

```
$detect = new Mobile_Detect();
$mobile = $detect->isMobile() and !$detect->isTablet();
```

vs

```
$detect = new Mobile_Detect();
$mobile = ($detect->isMobile() and !$detect->isTablet());
```

If I am a tablet (which is also considered mobile), the 1st example I was getting true for mobile. (Not expected). For the 2nd example I was getting false (as expected).

Why do I need parenthesis since it is just one and operator.

Comment: `and` has lower precedence than `=`, I suggest avoiding it because it's not as intuitive as `&&`

Comment: `=` has higher precedence than `and`. Are you sure you didn't mean `&&` instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To have a [more adequate precedence compared to =](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), use `&&` :

```
$mobile = $detect->isMobile() && !$detect->isTablet();
```

From the [documentation on logical operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) :

> The reason for the two different variations of "and" and "or"
>   operators is that they operate at different precedences.

Comment: I was only moderately aware that PHP even had the `and` keyword!

Comment: And it has lower priority than assignment. Just as you think PHP cannot be designed worse than it is ....

Comment: more adequate to what ? both sides are just a function call. this is no answer

Comment: @nl-x more adequate as in "it works for OP's needs even without added parenthesis".

Comment: ow sorry missed the part that the assignment itsself wasnt preceded. tricky one that `and` :) +1

Answer (score 3):

You need them, because the `=` sign has higher priority than `and`. Use `&&` and you can lose them.

Comment: Wow, that is very odd. At least I know now.